# Necessary condition for the space of continuous functions on an interval to be a closed linear subspace of $X$ Bannach function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

This is the definition which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]

There is the theorem:
[image]

I don't understand how do we get $(3.4)$ by the closed graph theorem.

There it is :
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles

Comment: @FShrike I don't know the name of this theorem

Comment: @FShrike the norm of a constant function is constant function itself . We are using this like that.

Answer (score 0):

The second inequality in (3.4) should be $\|f\|_X \le \|\chi_\Omega \|_X \|f\|_{C(I)}$, maybe there is a `wlog' statement to assume $\|\chi_\Omega \|_X=1$.

To use closed graph theorem to prove the first inequality, consider the operator $j:(C(I),\|\cdot\|_X) \to C(I)$, $j(f)=f$. Its graph is closed (trivially). The domain of $j$ is a Banach space (by assumption). Then $j$ is continuous, which is the desired inequality.

Comment: How did you get the second inequality  ? @daw